Does the shape of the collatz tree exhibit self-similar properties?
Note: Throughout this question I use the term "branch" to mean a part of the Collatz tree beginning with an odd number $n$ and then consisting of $n \cdot 2^k$ for all $k$.
My question should explain itself; here's some of my mental doodling. Say a branch of the Collatz tree is type $A$ if it begins with a number that is equal to $1$ mod $3$ (officially $1$ mod $6$, since the beginning of a branch must be odd). Starting from the top, the branch mod-$3$ will be $1,2,1,2,1,2...$ and so on. Therefore, this branch will spawn a new branch on every other number (when it is $1$ mod $3$, not counting the first number).
If the start of the branch is $2$ mod $3$, then call it type $B$. The mod-$3$ pattern is $2,1,2,1,2,1...$ and so we can see that a new branch will be spawned for every other number likewise to type $A$. Finally, if the branch is $0$ mod $3$, call it type $D$, for "dead" -- this is because the mod-$3$ pattern of this branch is $0,0,0,0...$ and so it will never spawn a new branch and thus is dead.
If a branch is the same type as the branch starting with $1$, if you look at it like its own tree, it should be a exact copy of the whole tree. But no -- for example, the first branch spawned by the branch starting with $7$ is dead, which is not true of the branch starting with $1$. So subcategorize; put the type of the first branch a branch spawns as subscript. For example, $7$ is type $A$, but it spawns a dead branch first; therefore it is type $A_D$. Note that type $A$ will always spawn branches in this order (but it can start from any one): $A, B, D, A, B, D...$ Similarly type $B$ will always spawn branches in the order $A, D, B, A, D, B...$
But we can keep going, for example with $13$; the first branch spawned by $13$ is in fact $B_B$, so $13$ is type $A_{B_B}$. You can see how this can go on forever (if an alive branch has a dead branch first, put the next branch's type after; for example $7$ is $A_{DA_A...}$). The question is then reduced to: do any branches of the Collatz tree have the same infinite type?
Maybe this is just all rambling. I don't know. Maybe this question is unanswerable. Even so, any help would be appreciated!

I'm not sure whether I got you correctly, but my style of graph, which looks like a bottelbrush might come near to your "self-similar structure? See "about numerical  and graphical trees" chapter in my amateurish treaty http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm

yes it is self-similar and it takes the form of an infinite binary rooted tree - or an infinite binary forest if the function doesn't act transitively.  I'll post as an answer if reopened.

@RobertFrost - The question was reopened... I'd be really curious to know what you're talking about! Would it be possible for you to post an answer?

I'll start with some terminology, then I'll define a structure which is not the one you described above, then I'll talk about your structure, which is actually a subset of the structure I described.
Some Terminology
The name for the tree of the orbits of a function is the functional graph.  The name "graph" rather than "tree" reflects the fact that it may actually be a "forest" - i.e. the function may not act transitively i.e. it may have multiple distinct orbits.  It also reflects the fact a functional graph is directed, i.e. it flows in the direction the function acts rather than the opposite, in this case $x\mapsto (3x+1)/2$.
If the Collatz conjecture is true then the Collatz functional graph has a single connected orbit over the natural numbers, over which it acts transitively.
The larger structure - over $\Bbb Z[\frac13]$
The function is most commonly defined by having two choices going forwards - i.e. $x\mapsto (3x+1)/2$ when $x$ is odd and $x\mapsto x/2$ when $x$ is even.
Now because the functions $x\mapsto (3x+1)/2$ and $x\mapsto x/2$ are both bijective over $\Bbb Q$, for any given $x$, we can always identify (in $\Bbb Q$) precisely two predecessors or children of $x$.  The predecessors of any given $x$ are the inverse functions of those - i.e. $x\mapsto (2x-1)/3$ and $x\mapsto 2x$.
From this, assuming the Collatz conjecture is true, it is possible to deduce (by simply starting with $1$ and mapping the two predecessors of every number) that the functional graph is actually an infinite, binary rooted tree, covering all of $\Bbb Z[\frac13]^+$.  By this set I mean all of the products of positive ternary fractions - i.e. all the positive rational numbers which have only powers of three on the bottom.
No other denominators than powers of three can be created because one can see that neither $x\mapsto (2x-1)/3$ nor $x\mapsto 2x$ can ever create any other.
The fact all such fractions are connected to $\Bbb N$ is easily deduced because if there is a power of $3$ on the bottom then $3x+1$ will have a lower power of three than $x$, and since the exponents are finite and descending, they will eventually reach $3^0$.
Now I told a little lie earlier, where I said the infinite, binary rooted tree covers all of $\Bbb Z[\frac13]^+$, it actually covers some negative numbers too because when $x$ gets less than a half, $(2x-1)/3$ can be less than zero.
Your structure
You have essentially abstracted away the divisions by two.  This can be looked at in various ways but essentially think of every odd number $x$ as the representative of $x\cdot2^t:t\in\Bbb Z$ so then the collatz function goes e.g. $3\mapsto5\mapsto1$.
Now hark back to my structure which had $x\mapsto 2x$ spawning a "child".  When you set $x\sim2x$ like you have done, this means all the children of those $2^tx$ look like immediate children of $x$.  So e.g. $1,5,21,85,341...$ are all children of $1$.  So instead of an infinite binary rooted tree, you now have an infinite infinitary rooted tree, with every vertex having infinitely many "children".
In fact I listed only the integer children of $1$ but those are a subset of the larger tree which contains $\frac13,1,2\frac13,5,10\frac13,21,42\frac13,\ldots$ all of which go immediately to $1$.
And here is where we can see the structure of your tree.  In any increasing sequence of children of any given natural number, you will find that alternate numbers are integers.  And every third integer is a multiple of $3$.  And as you correctly observed, none of the fractions are integers (and therefore will never have any integer children) and also none of the multiples of $3$ willever have any integer children.  So what you described is actually a filtered subgraph of an infinite binary rooted tree over $\Bbb Z[\frac13]$,and each sequence of children has $6$ possible starting positions.
You then go on to ask what we know about how these sequences give way to each other and your question appears to ask what patterns may exist in relation to how those six starting positions give way to each other.
Now there are various theorems which may cover this but it has been proven that if we record whether a Collatz sequence over the natural numbers is odd or even, then every finite binary sequence of odd/even is represented.  This is strongly suggestive that every pattern you inquire about is covered somewhere.
